# Incompatible types when assigning to type - C

Tags: c, pointers, types, double

I'm working in Code::Blocks on a project in C.

When I compile I get the error: "incompatible types when assigning to type 'double *' from type 'double'" on lines 81, 85, 90, 91.

The project is to take a unit conversion tool and incorporate multiple functions instead of everything under the main().

http://pastebay.net/1181184

Comment: Do NOT reference code with an external link. (how do we know its not filled with viruses?)   Reduce your code to a meaningful, small size, and put it directly in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Try dereferencing the pointer:

```
*pKelvin = PROD((fahrenheit+459.67),ytemp);
^
```

Comment: haha you beat me too it

Answer (score 3):

All of the errors you're getting are variations on a theme.  Take this line, for example:

```
pKelvin = PROD((fahrenheit+459.67),ytemp);
```

Here, `pKelvin` has type `double*`, meaning that it's a pointer to an object of type `double`.  On the other hand, the right-hand side has type `double`, meaning that it's an actual `double`.  C is complaining because you can't assign `double`s to `double*`s, since they represent fundamentally different types.

To fix this, you probably want to write

```
*pKelvin = PROD((fahrenheit+459.67),ytemp);
```

This says "store the value of `PROD((fahrenheit+459.67),ytemp)` at the `double` pointed at by `pKelvin`.  This works because you're now assigning a `double` to an object of type `double`.

More generally, if you ever see an error like this one, it probably means you're assigning a pointer to a non-pointer or vice-versa.

Hope this helps!