# Pointer error C

Tags: c

I need to write this code for school.  It has to search the minimum and maximum of an array. I get an error :

incompatible types when assigning to type 'double *' from type 'double'

How can I make it work?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void minmax(double tomb[], double* mini , double* maxi) {
 int i;
 mini=&tomb[0];
 maxi=&tomb[0];
 for(i=1; i<10; i++){
     if(tomb[i]>*maxi){
         maxi=&tomb[i];
     }
     if(tomb[i]<*mini){
         mini=&tomb[i];
     }
 }
}


int main(void) {
  double t[] = {1.2, 2.3, 6.1, -3, -2.7, 2.7, 11.11, -20, 0.23, 4.1};
  double min, max;
  minmax(t, double* min, double* max);
  printf("%lf\n%lf\n", min, max);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incompatible types when assigning to type - C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765788/incompatible-types-when-assigning-to-type-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to replace this line:

```
minmax(t, double* min, double* max);
```

with:

```
minmax(t, &min, &max);
```

Using `&` means you're passing the address of the variable, which is what the function `minmax` is expecting (since it uses pointers, it's expecting the address).

PS: normally, you have to pass the size of the array along with the array when you pass it to a function. You've hardcoded the size of the array into the function, which works great in this case. In the future, try to remember to pass the array along with it's size; it's good C coding practice.

**EDIT after OP comment**

Here is the function, with comments to indicate changes to make in the function:

```
void minmax(double tomb[], double* mini , double* maxi) {
    int i;
    *mini=tomb[0]; // change here; original: mini=&tomb[0];
    *maxi=tomb[0]; // change here; original: maxi=&tomb[0];
    for(i=1; i<10; i++){
        if(tomb[i]>*maxi){
            *maxi=tomb[i]; // change here; original: maxi=&tomb[i];
        }
        if(tomb[i]<*mini){
            *mini=tomb[i]; // change here; original: mini=&tomb[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello again

now it runs, but  returns a gorgeus stupidness:
0.00000000
11911148967105177000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

any idea how could i make it work?
i need to print the min and the max item of the array.

Comment: @user3666276 I have edited my answer to show a couple of changes to make in the `minmax` function. Let me know how it goes.